# Flutter - Build Widgets dynamically

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to build a List of widgets dynamically

```
List<Widget> buildGrid(){
List<Widget> grid = new List<Widget>(3);
List<Widget> tiles = [];
int counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  tiles = [];
  for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
    tiles.add(new GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        setState((){
          toggleColor(counter);
        });
      },
      child: new Container(
        color: colors[counter],
        width: 80.0,
        height: 80.0,
        margin: new EdgeInsets.all(11.3),
      )
    ));
    counter++;
  }
  grid[i] = new Row(
    children: tiles,
  );
  counter = 0;
}
return grid;


}
```

The problem with this is, that the toggleColor of the newly added element is always 12. I meant it to add a new GestureDetector with the current iteration of counter, so that if the user clicks on an element, it only colors it. If I set counter to 3 for example, everything gets selected because it is still refering to the counter variable, instead of to the current interation, if you know what I mean.

Any suggestions on how I can solve this problem efficently?

Comment: github.com/francesco-taioli/flutter-card-demo you can see how create element programattically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to capture the current value of the counter variable into a closure:

```
final _createTapHandler = (value) {
    setState(() => toggleColor(value));
};
```

Then you can say:

```
onTap: _createTapHandler(counter)
```

Perhaps a more maintainable solution would be to create a method that builds your GestureRecognizer. Then you could configure it with the counter value.

```
Widget buildTile(int tileCounter) {
  return new GestureDetector(
    onTap: (){
      setState((){
        toggleColor(tileCounter);
      });
    },
    child: new Container(
      color: colors[tileCounter],
      width: 80.0,
      height: 80.0,
      margin: new EdgeInsets.all(11.3),
    )
  );
}
```

You could refactor that build function into its own StatelessWidget if you want to be even more maintainable.

Comment: Where do I need to place the closure?

Comment: Anywhere, you could even declare it inline. onTap: ((value) { setState(() => toggleColor(value)); })(counter)