# Flutter - Dynamic list with data coming from the database

Tags: database, sqlite, dart, flutter

I needed to create the `DialogItem` widgets using the data that comes from the database. I tried to use `for(){}` but it did not work.

Could you help me solve this problem?

I put the used code as well as the evidence that works, just does not work the dynamic list of `DialogItem` with the data of the database.

To work the code below, you need to insert the `sqflite` and `path_provider` dependencies into `pubspec.yaml`, thus:

```
dependencies:
  sqflite: any
  path_provider: any
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

The `DatabaseClient` class will create the database with 3 records.

In the gif only `foo1` appears the correct one would be to appear all the values of the list that came from the database:

`[{name: foo1, color: 0}, {name: foo2, color: 1}, {name: foo3, color: 2}]`

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  DatabaseClient _db = new DatabaseClient();
  int number;
  List listCategory;

  List colors = [
    const Color(0xFFFFA500),
    const Color(0xFF279605),
    const Color(0xFF005959)
  ];

  createdb() async {
    await _db.create().then(
      (data){
        _db.countCategory().then((list){
          this.number = list[0][0]['COUNT(*)']; //3
          this.listCategory = list[1];
          //[{name: foo1, color: 0}, {name: foo2, color: 1}, {name: foo3, color: 2}]
        });
      }
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    createdb();    
  }

  void showCategoryDialog<T>({ BuildContext context, Widget child }) {
    showDialog<T>(
      context: context,
      child: child,
    )
    .then<Null>((T value) {
      if (value != null) {
        setState(() { print(value); });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      body: new Center(
        child: new RaisedButton(
          onPressed: (){           
            showCategoryDialog<String>(
              context: context,
              child: new SimpleDialog(
                title: const Text('Categories'),
                children: <Widget>[
                  //for(var i = 0; i < this.number; i++) {
                    new DialogItem(
                      icon: Icons.brightness_1,
                      color: this.colors[
                        this.listCategory[0]['color']
                        //the zero should be dynamic going from 0 to 2 with the for(){}
                        //but o for(){} dont work
                      ],
                      text: this.listCategory[0]['name'],
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context, this.listCategory[0]['name']);
                      }
                    ),
                  //}                  
                ]
              )
            );
          },
          child: new Text("ListButton"),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}

//Creating Database with some data and two queries
class DatabaseClient {
  Database db;

  Future create() async {
    Directory path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String dbPath = join(path.path, "database.db");
    db = await openDatabase(dbPath, version: 1, onCreate: this._create);
  }

  Future _create(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE category (
              id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
              name TEXT NOT NULL,
              color INTEGER NOT NULL
            )""");
    await db.rawInsert("INSERT INTO category (name, color) VALUES ('foo1', 0)");
    await db.rawInsert("INSERT INTO category (name, color) VALUES ('foo2', 1)");
    await db.rawInsert("INSERT INTO category (name, color) VALUES ('foo3', 2)");
  }

  Future countCategory() async {
    Directory path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String dbPath = join(path.path, "database.db");
    Database db = await openDatabase(dbPath);

    var count = await db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM category");
    List list = await db.rawQuery('SELECT name, color FROM category');
    await db.close();

    return [count, list];
  }
}

//Class of Dialog Item
class DialogItem extends StatelessWidget {
  DialogItem({ 
    Key key,
    this.icon,
    this.size,
    this.color,
    this.text,
    this.onPressed }) : super(key: key);

  final IconData icon;
  double size = 36.0;
  final Color color;
  final String text;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SimpleDialogOption(
      onPressed: onPressed,
      child: new Container(
        child: new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(              
              child: new Container(
                margin: size == 16.0 ? new EdgeInsets.only(left: 7.0) : null,
                child: new Icon(icon, size: size, color: color),
              )                
            ),        
            new Padding(
              padding: size == 16.0 ?
                const EdgeInsets.only(left: 17.0) :
                const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
              child: new Text(text),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, according to the [Flutter - Build Widgets dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074797/flutter-build-widgets-dynamically) and [Flutter - Combine dynamically generated elements with hard-coded ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44306856/flutter-combine-dynamically-generated-elements-with-hard-coded-ones) and in this question

As `SimpleDialog` only accepts a `List` of type `Widget` - `<Widget>[]` I declare a variable `tiles` of type `List<Widget>` - `List<Widget> tiles;` and created a function of type `List<Widget>` - `List<Widget> buildTile(int counter) {...` - to be able to return a `List<Widget>`

Because of `Navigator.pop (context, ...` I needed to create the `buildTile()` function inside the `Widget build(BuildContext context) {...`

In the `buildTile()` function I added a `for()` to insert into the `Widget` type list as many `DialogItem Widgets` were needed, according to the result that comes from the database

and wrap the code that updates the state with `setState(() {...})` as explained by Günter Zöchbauer

```
setState(() {
  this.number = list[0][0]['COUNT(*)']; //3
  this.listCategory = list[1];
  //[{name: foo1, color: 0}, {name: foo2, color: 1}, {name: foo3, color: 2}]
})
```

The complete code working as well as the demo are below:

To work the code below, you need to insert the `sqflite` and `path_provider` dependencies into `pubspec.yaml`, thus:

```
dependencies:
  sqflite: any
  path_provider: any
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  DatabaseClient _db = new DatabaseClient();
  int number;
  List listCategory;
  List<Widget> tiles;

  List colors = [
    const Color(0xFFFFA500),
    const Color(0xFF279605),
    const Color(0xFF005959)
  ];

  createdb() async {
    await _db.create().then(
      (data){
        _db.countCategory().then((list){
          setState(() {
            this.number = list[0][0]['COUNT(*)']; //3
            this.listCategory = list[1];            
            //[{name: foo1, color: 0}, {name: foo2, color: 1}, {name: foo3, color: 2}]
          });          
        });
      }
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    createdb();    
  }

  void showCategoryDialog<T>({ BuildContext context, Widget child }) {
    showDialog<T>(
      context: context,
      child: child,
    )
    .then<Null>((T value) {
      if (value != null) {
        setState(() { print(value); });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<Widget> buildTile(int counter) {
      this.tiles = [];
      for(var i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        this.tiles.add(
          new DialogItem(
            icon: Icons.brightness_1,
            color: this.colors[
              this.listCategory[i]['color']
            ],
            text: this.listCategory[i]['name'],
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context, this.listCategory[i]['name']);
            }
          )
        );
      }
      return this.tiles;
    }

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      body: new Center(
        child: new RaisedButton(
          onPressed: (){           
            showCategoryDialog<String>(
              context: context,
              child: new SimpleDialog(
                title: const Text('Categories'),
                children: buildTile(this.number)
              )
            );
          },
          child: new Text("ListButton"),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}

//Creating Database with some data and two queries
class DatabaseClient {
  Database db;

  Future create() async {
    Directory path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String dbPath = join(path.path, "database.db");
    db = await openDatabase(dbPath, version: 1, onCreate: this._create);
  }

  Future _create(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE category (
              id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
              name TEXT NOT NULL,
              color INTEGER NOT NULL
            )""");
    await db.rawInsert("INSERT INTO category (name, color) VALUES ('foo1', 0)");
    await db.rawInsert("INSERT INTO category (name, color) VALUES ('foo2', 1)");
    await db.rawInsert("INSERT INTO category (name, color) VALUES ('foo3', 2)");
  }

  Future countCategory() async {
    Directory path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String dbPath = join(path.path, "database.db");
    Database db = await openDatabase(dbPath);

    var count = await db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM category");
    List list = await db.rawQuery('SELECT name, color FROM category');
    await db.close();

    return [count, list];
  }
}

//Class of Dialog Item
class DialogItem extends StatelessWidget {
  DialogItem({ 
    Key key,
    this.icon,
    this.size,
    this.color,
    this.text,
    this.onPressed }) : super(key: key);

  final IconData icon;
  double size = 36.0;
  final Color color;
  final String text;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SimpleDialogOption(
      onPressed: onPressed,
      child: new Container(
        child: new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(              
              child: new Container(
                margin: size == 16.0 ? new EdgeInsets.only(left: 7.0) : null,
                child: new Icon(icon, size: size, color: color),
              )                
            ),        
            new Padding(
              padding: size == 16.0 ?
                const EdgeInsets.only(left: 17.0) :
                const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
              child: new Text(text),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There might be other issues, but as a start, I think this code

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.number; i++) {
  ...
}
```

should be changed to

```
children: this.number == null ? null :  
  new List(this.number).map((i) => 
    new DialogItem(
      icon: Icons.brightness_1,
      color: this.colors[
        this.listCategory[0]['color']
        //the zero should be dynamic going from 0 to 2 with the for(){}
        //but o for(){} dont work
      ],
      text: this.listCategory[0]['name'],
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context, this.listCategory[0]['name']);
      }
    ).toList(),
```

to not throw an exception when `this.number` is `null` (response not yet received from the database).

and wrap the code that updates the state with `setState(() {...})`

```
  createdb() async {
    await _db.create().then(
      (data){
        _db.countCategory().then((list){
          setState(() {
            this.number = list[0][0]['COUNT(*)']; //3
            this.listCategory = list[1];
          //[{name: foo1, color: 0}, {name: foo2, color: 1}, {name: foo3, color: 2}]
          });
        });
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: in `for()` appears the errors, `[dart] Expected to find ')'.` 
`[dart] Expected to find ']'.` and `[dart] Expected an identifier.` But it closes correctly, it seems that does not let put `if()` or `for()` inside a `children list: <Widget>[]`

Comment: Hm, I don't think one can use a `for` in a `List` constructor, you probably could do something [like this](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/44168616e8bb31e94f8021ec261f3f5b).

Comment: Duh, I totally missed, that you don't need to build the list by hand lol - great solution :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the `new List(this.number).map((i) =>...` solution is giving the following error `Invalid argument(s)`  `_List.[] (dart:core-patch/dart:core/array.dart:11)` the error occurs when I tap the button

Comment: Is this at runtime or in the IDE?

Comment: Occurs in the debug of the app in runtime, but the error appear in IDE, not displaying the `ShowDialog`.

Comment: But thanks to your idea of generating the list instead of generating the elements of the list I found the solution based on other stackflows

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.